# Codename One - Social login with Twitter and Yahoo

Tags: codenameone

I have to implement a social login in my Codename One app with Twitter and Yahoo.

In the Uber clone (Codename One Academy) and in a chat tutorial in the Codename One website I found useful information to implement Google and Facebook login.

I need informations, hints, tutorials, code... or, however, any help to do the login with Twitter and Yahoo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are two approaches, you can use the OAuth2 class which you can implement in the simulator and works like any standard oauth 2.x web login. This was mentioned by Steve here: [How can I use twitter for sign in to my Codename one application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137381/how-can-i-use-twitter-for-sign-in-to-my-codename-one-application)

If you really want to go the extra mile you can integrate the native SDK for login on the device. That usually requires a bit more work but not as much. The only challenging part with native SDK logins would be the callback URL's which are discussed in the developer guide.